# GestureDetector cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, gesturedetector

I'm learning to use GestureDetector and following android's official developer's guide, but when I try to run a snippet of code I met a problem..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{}
```

Here Eclipse gives me a error: GestureDetector cannot be resolved to a type, I tried to fixed it by cleaning and rebuilding, re-import android support library and including it in the build path and pressing ctrl+shift+o as well..but my Eclipse is just not letting this error go away...

Please give me some advice and I really appreciate that.

P.S., I'm following codes on [Android Gesture Detector Training](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Answer (score 10):

try writing this code in your activity

```
  import android.view.GestureDetector;
```

This will do the trick.